# Have enumerations rendered final variables obsolete?

Tags: java, enumeration, final

I am new to java and could not get whether enumerations rendered final variables obsolete?

Answer (score 2):

Enumerations and final variables unrelated. Prior to enums people had to resort to constants, but they are not equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not. Final variables in Java ate for more than just constants.

- Final can be applied to method parameters to provide a compile-time guarantee against reassignment.
- Final can be applied to local variables to provide a compile-time guarantee against reassignment. This also is REQUIRED for instantiating anonymous inner classes that reference local variables (also known as closures).
- Final can be applied to instance variables to guarantee reference immutability of those fields. If the field type is immutable or suitable defensive measures are taken, this can be used to ensure your object's immutability, making it trivially thread safe.
- Final can be applied to methods to prevent subclasses from overriding them.
- Final can be applied to classes to prevent extension of the class at all.

As you can see, there are still PLENTY of uses for the `final` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

I assume in this question you are asking about integer constants rather than of any other type?  If not, remember that enums can only be enums (ints) and can not be of a particular type.

Otherwise... again, it would not make them obsolete. Enums are useful where there are only a (small-ish) finite number of possibilities that will never change.  Not so useful where these can be an infinite number of things (or a large number) or are not all fully defined but some can be.

It really depends on the usage.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `public static final int` variables used as named constants, then yes, enumerations are intended to be used in their stead.

However, final variables are still useful in a few regions -- notably, the use of closures requires them, e.g.

```
final int foo = 3; // must be marked final
t = new Thread(new Runnable() { 
    public static void run() { 
        System.out.println(foo + 1);
    }
});
t.start();
```

In addition, PSF variables are still useful as configuration constants.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are different applications for both.  Enumerations are better for stuff like state machines  or places where values are not relevant.  I have a set of final variables that function as both values and state indicators in one of my programs.  Final variables still have significant applications because they allow the simple modification of literal values throughout an entire program.

/nutshell